# What is application_name in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm new in sugarcrm. Now I have trial credentials. I need to know what is application_name and what I'll put when I got real account credentails

```
$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth" => array(
          "user_name" => $user,
          "password" => md5($pass),
          "version" => "1"
     ),
     "application_name" => "RestTest",
     "name_value_list" => array(),
);
```

Comment: It's the name of your web application when using the Sugar API. It's just for logging purposes.

Comment: Ok. But when and how that "web application" name is created.